# Revision null al enviar el formulario

Tags: php, symfony2, doctrine2

tengo un formulario con varios embebidos.
Tengo la entidad Presupuesto, la cual tiene relacion oneToMany con Revision, y revision tiene oneToMany con Capitulo, Capitulo tiene tambien oneToMany con otra llamada Requisito, pero no hace falta indagar mas ya que mi problema esta entre Capitulo y Requisito.
No se porque, cuando agrego un capitulo con addTagForm y esta relleno con todo, al enviar el formulario parece haber ido todo bien, pero para mi sorpresa todas las relaciones se han enlazado bien menos Capitulo con Revision, he echo un dump antes de hacer el persist de presupuesto, y he encontrado que cuando navego en el dump hasta llegar al Capitulo, el atributo de revision_id esta a null.
Alguna idea? A continuacion os dejo fragmentos de codigo que considero mas relevantes:

Revision.php

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="CeiferIT\ComercialBundle\Entity\Capitulo", mappedBy="revision", cascade={"persist"}, orphanRemoval=true)
 */
protected $capitulos;

/**
 * @param \CeiferIT\ComercialBundle\Entity\Capitulo $capitulo
 *
 * @return Revision
 */
public function addCapitulo(\CeiferIT\ComercialBundle\Entity\Capitulo $capitulo)
{
    $capitulo->setRevision($this);
    $this->capitulos[] = $capitulo;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * @param \CeiferIT\ComercialBundle\Entity\Capitulo $capitulo
 */
public function removeCapitulo(\CeiferIT\ComercialBundle\Entity\Capitulo $capitulo)
{
    $this->capitulos->removeElement($capitulo);
}

/**
 * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
 */
public function getCapitulos()
{
    return $this->capitulos;
}
```

Capitulo.php

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="CeiferIT\ComercialBundle\Entity\Revision", inversedBy="capitulos", cascade={"persist"})
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="revision_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $revision;

/**
 * @param \CeiferIT\ComercialBundle\Entity\Revision $revision
 *
 * @return Capitulo
 */
public function setRevision(\CeiferIT\ComercialBundle\Entity\Revision $revision = null)
{
    $this->revision = $revision;
    return $this;
}

/**
 * @return \CeiferIT\ComercialBundle\Entity\Revision
 */
public function getRevision()
{
    return $this->revision;
}
```

nuevo.html.twig

```
{{ form_start(formulario) }}
//some code..
{% include 'ComercialBundle:Presupuesto:listaRevisiones.html.twig' %}
//some code..
{{ form_end(formulario) }}
```

listaRevisiones.html.twig

```
{% macro information_prototype(revision) %}
    {% if form_errors(revision.total) %}
        {{ form_widget(revision.total, {'attr': {'class': 'form-control totalrevision error'}}) }}
    {% else %}
        {{ form_widget(revision.total, {'attr': {'class': 'form-control totalrevision'}}) }}
    {% endif %}
    {% include 'ComercialBundle:Presupuesto:listacapitulos.html.twig' %}
{% endmacro %}

<div class="ibox product-box active primerarevision" data-prototype="{{ _self.information_prototype(formulario.revisiones.vars.prototype)|e}}">
{% for revision in formulario.revisiones %}
    {{ _self.information_prototype(revision)}}
{% endfor %}
</div>
```

Comment: Sería bueno que agregaras el código de tu FormType y de tu Controller relacionados a dicho formulario, además del error que se te genera.

Answer (score 1):

Revisaste el schema?

```
app/console doctrine:schema:validate
```

Cuando el mapeo genera error, los formularios no funcionan correctamente con las relaciones; además, uno suele usar en la función 'OneToMany' una función

```
public function __toString() 
{
    return $StringQueUsarasDeRetorno;
}
```

Con ésta función, le indicas al formulario qué aportar en el campo del formulario que presenta la relación